# saving simple values in iOS leads to a large documents and data file

Tags: ios, nsdocumentdirectory

I am developing a simple iOS game and my app size is only 3 mb
this is the code I use to save the users high scores

the problem is that every time I use the app, its documents and data file size increases. it reached 28 mb on my iPad. why is this happening ? 
any help is appreciated

```
     - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
NSArray *value = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:easyHighscoreFloat],[NSNumber numberWitFloat:normalHighscoreFloat],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:hardHighscoreFloat],nil];
[value writeToFile:[self saveHighScore] atomically:YES];
}




    -(NSString*)saveHighScore{
NSArray *filePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
return [[filePath objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedState.plist"];
 }




- (void)viewDidLoad{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];

     NSString *path = [self saveHighScore];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:path];

if (fileExists) {

    NSArray *loadValues = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    easyHighscoreFloat = [[loadValues objectAtIndex:0]floatValue];
    normalHighscoreFloat = [[loadValues objectAtIndex:1]floatValue];
    hardHighscoreFloat = [[loadValues objectAtIndex:2]floatValue];

}else{
    easyHighscoreFloat = 0;
    normalHighscoreFloat = 0;
    hardHighscoreFloat = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the data in the large file look like?

Comment: is there a way to see this file ?. I only know how big it is from the settings app (settings->general->usage)

Comment: Run the app on the simulator. Then go to <your user acct>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<version of simulator>/Applications/<your app>/Documents. Since you are storing your file in the Documents directory, you should be able to see the file in the path I mentioned and you can open it to check the contents.

Comment: I just did as you proposed and I found my saved values in a plist file, its size is only 355 bytes !

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't coming the above code block, why is it that the documents and data of my app as shown in the settings app is over 20 mb , does this happen for everyone ?